# How detect all the asynchronous operations are finished on Retrofit like Promise in Javascript?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, retrofit2

I have an application that makes dynamic requests by Retrofit and i want to detect if all have finished with the best practice like I know how to make in javascript with Promise.

In Retrofit today I'm doing like this, I receive an array from objects and i will make x request depending on the size of the array.

So when I start the function I pick the size from an array and every time my Retrofit makes a call I put in my variable **successCounter++ and errorCounter++**, when sum from this 2 variables is equal my array size, so this is the end of the asynchronous functions.

But I don't know if this is a good practice an example from my peace of code:

```
 String filePath = system.getMp_user_name() + "/categorias/" + mpCategory.getImg();
                            downloadImage("category", filePath, mpCategory.getImg(),
                                    new SynService.ApiImageCallback() {
                                        public void onResponse(Boolean success, Integer requestCounter, Integer errorRequestCounter){
                                            if(success){
                                                categoryImgSuccessCounter++;
                                                Log.d(TAG, "Imagem baixada e armazenada com sucesso");
                                                if(categoryImgSuccessCounter.equals(arrayCategorySize)) {
                                                    HashMap<String, String> responseObj = new HashMap<>();
                                                    responseObj.put("success", "1");
                                                    responseObj.put("message", "Sincronização Completada com Sucesso");
                                                    callback.onResponse(responseObj);
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                categoryImgErrorCounter++;
                                                Log.d(TAG, "Não foi possível fazer o download da imagem");
                                                HashMap<String, String> responseObj = new HashMap<>();
                                                responseObj.put("success", "0");
                                                responseObj.put("message", "Houve um erro no download das imagens e o processo parou");
                                                callback.onResponse(responseObj);
                                            }
                                            Integer total = categoryImgSuccessCounter + categoryImgErrorCounter;
                                            if(total.equals(arrayCategorySize)) {
                                                categoryImgFinished = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
```

How can I detect when all the request from Retrofit is finished without a counter?

In javascript is just this:

```
async function foo(things) {
  const results = [];
  for (const thing of things) {
    // Good: all asynchronous operations are immediately started.
    results.push(bar(thing));
  }
  // Now that all the asynchronous operations are running, here we wait until they all complete.
  return baz(await Promise.all(results));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Interceptor`of Retrofit to intercept each request and do the counter increment/decrement and shares the callback on the basis of that.

> Interceptors are a powerful mechanism that can monitor, rewrite, and retry calls.

[Interceptor - How to?](https://square.github.io/okhttp/interceptors/)

---

If it's okay to add one dependency then add `RxJava` and it has good number of operator which are useful for multithreading and it's callback.

To wait until all your requests will be done is to use `Retrofit2` in conjunction with `RxJava2`with its zip function.

> Zip combine the emissions of multiple Observables together via a specified function and emit single items for each combination based on the results of this function

Add `RxJava2CallAdapterFactory` as a Call adapter when building your `Retrofit` instance:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.example.com/")
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();
```

Your service methods can now use any of the above types as their return type.

```
interface MyService {
  @GET("/user")
  Observable<User> getUser();
}


MyService retrofitApi = retrofit.create(MyService.class);
```

Use that service to create the collection of request and zip those requests.

```
// You need to use `Observable` type for the response.
List<Observable<?>> requests = new ArrayList<>();

// Make a collection of all requests
requests.add(retrofitApi.getUser());
requests.add(retrofitApi.getUser());
requests.add(retrofitApi.getUser());

// Zip all requests with the Function, which will receive the results.
Observable.zip(
        requests,
        new Function<Object[], Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {
                // Objects[] is an array of combined results of completed requests

                // do something with those results and emit new event
                return new Object();
            }
        })
        // After all requests had been performed the next observer will receive the Object, returned from Function
        .subscribe(
                // Will be triggered if all requests will end successfully (4xx and 5xx also are successful requests too)
                new Consumer<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Object o) throws Exception {
                        //Do something on successful completion of all requests
                    }
                },

                // Will be triggered if any error during requests will happen
                new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable e) throws Exception {
                        //Do something on error completion of requests
                    }
                }
        );
```

Comment: OMG, really thanks I didn't know that exists a RxJava, but u can some a sample code to work on my code?